# How to use c# to turn files into pictures and return them to the front end?Is to convert bolb into base64

Tags: c#, file, stream

file stream to jpg/JPEG
c#
How to use c# to turn files into pictures and return them to the front end?Is to convert bolb into base64.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Charlieface

Thank you very much, I want to convert the word file into pdf, and realize the function of previewing in the browser through this. It has been completed using the word plug-in. Thank you for your answer.